# Login manager uses too much cpu

Tags: 16.04, login, login-screen, cpu-load

I used to use lightdm as login manager then I noticed that it was using too much CPU .Now I am using slim but still slim uses a lot of CPU it uses minimum 5 percent of CPU . its the on the top when you can see htop the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Please define "too much CPU".

Comment: Min 5 percent CPU as I mentioned above

Comment: This looks all perfectly acceptable to me